# Яндекс карта. Js

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Сделал яндекс карту, с кастомным поиском. Всё ищется, но я хотел бы что бы при клике на элемент поиска, он отображался на карте. Как это сделать?

```
function init() {
  const myMap = new ymaps.Map(
    "map",
    { 
      center: [55.755494501090126,37.64353399999998],
      zoom: 14.5, 
    },
  );

  var points = [
      "Москва, SitDownPls на Солянке м. Китай-город, ул. Солянка, д.24",
      "Москва, SitDownPls на Покровке м. Курская, ул. Покровка, д.14"
    // { coords: [55.750615568993275,37.64180899999995], text: "Москва, SitDownPls на Солянке м. Китай-город, ул. Солянка, д.24" },
    // { coords: [55.75863431277058,37.64210467193599], text: "Москва, SitDownPls на Покровке м. Курская, ул. Покровка, д.14" },
    ];

    var find = function (points, find) {
      return points.filter(function (value) {
          return (value + "").toLowerCase().indexOf(find.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      });
  };

  
  var myProvider = {
    suggest: function (request, options) {
        var res = find(points, request),
            arrayResult = [],
            results = Math.min(options.results, res.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < results; i++) {
                arrayResult.push({displayName: res[i], value: res[i]})
            }
        return ymaps.vow.resolve(arrayResult);
    }
}

var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('search-input', {provider: myProvider, results: 2});
  const myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.750615568993275,37.64180899999995], {
    balloonContent: `

          <div class="contacts__balloon balloon">
          <div class="balloon__top">
            <h2 class="balloon__title">SitDownPls на Солянке </h2>
            <address class="balloon__address">м. Китай-город, ул. Солянка, д.24</address>
            <a href="tel:+74958854547" class="balloon__link">
              <svg class="balloon__svg" width="22" height="22">
                <use xlink:href="./images/svg/sprites.svg#call-icon"></use>
              </svg>
              +7 (495) 885-45-47
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="balloon__center">
            <p class="balloon__clockwork"><span class="balloon__span">Часы работы:</span> с 10:00 до 21:00</p>
          </div>
          <div class="balloon__bottom">
            <p class="balloon__descr">
              <span class="balloon__span">Что здесь:</span> шоурум, пункт отгрузки, пункт выдачи, пункт обмена-возврата, сервисный центр
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

    `
  }, {
      iconLayout: "default#image",
      iconImageHref: "../images/svg/elephant-map.svg",
      iconImageSize: [32, 23],
      iconImageOffset: [0, 0],
      hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
      balloonOffset: [0, -10]
    }
  );

  const myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([55.75863431277058,37.64210467193599], {
    balloonContent: `

          <div class="contacts__balloon balloon">
          <div class="balloon__top">
            <h2 class="balloon__title">SitDownPls на Покровке </h2>
            <address class="balloon__address">м. Курская, ул. Покровка, д.14</address>
            <a href="tel:+74958854547" class="balloon__link">
              <svg class="balloon__svg" width="22" height="22">
                <use xlink:href="./images/svg/sprites.svg#call-icon"></use>
              </svg>
              +7 (495) 885-45-47
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="balloon__center">
            <p class="balloon__clockwork"><span class="balloon__span">Часы работы:</span> с 10:00 до 21:00</p>
          </div>
          <div class="balloon__bottom">
            <p class="balloon__descr">
              <span class="balloon__span">Что здесь:</span> шоурум, пункт отгрузки, пункт выдачи, пункт обмена-возврата, сервисный центр
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

    `
  }, {
      iconLayout: "default#image",
      iconImageHref: "../images/svg/elephant-map.svg",
      iconImageSize: [32, 23],
      iconImageOffset: [0, 0],
      balloonOffset: [0, -10],
      hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
    }
  );

  myMap.controls.remove('geolocationControl'); // удаляем геолокацию
  myMap.controls.remove('searchControl'); // удаляем поиск
  myMap.controls.remove('trafficControl'); // удаляем контроль трафика
  myMap.controls.remove('typeSelector'); // удаляем тип
  myMap.controls.remove('fullscreenControl'); // удаляем кнопку перехода в полноэкранный режим
  myMap.controls.remove('zoomControl');  // удаляем контрол зуммирования
  myMap.controls.remove('rulerControl'); // удаляем контрол правил

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
  myPlacemark.balloon.open(); 
}
ymaps.ready(init);
```

https://codepen.io/exigo/pen/poWWaag Ссылка на код

Answer (score 0):

```
function showPlacemark(map, placemark) {
    map.setCenter(placemark.geometry.coordinates);
    placemark.balloon.open();
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]